# Perform share calculations in MongoDB aggregation

Tags: mongodb

I have an Order schema, like so:

```
const orderSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    order_items: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'OrderItem',
        required: true
    }],
    user: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
        required: true
    }
    total_price: {
        type: Number
    }
});
```

And the OrderItems contains purchased products, like so:

```
const orderItemSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    product_id: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Product',
        required: true
    },
    quantity: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    }
});
```

And the Product schema like so:

```
const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: Map,
        of: String,
        required: true
    },
    thumbnail: {
        type: String,
        default: ''
    },
    unit_price: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    }
});
```

I'm trying to get the share of each purchased product from the total price of the order.

I tried the following:

```
const totalSales = await Order.aggregate([
        {
            $lookup: {
                from: "orderitems",
                localField: "order_items",
                foreignField: "_id",
                as: "order_items"
            }
        },
        {
            $lookup: {
                from: "products",
                localField: "order_items.product_id",
                foreignField: "_id",
                as: "products",
                pipeline: []
            }
        },
        {
            $project: {
                order_items: 0,
                products: { $divide: ['$products.unit_price', '$total_price'] }
            }
        }
    ]);
```

But I got the following error in postman:

> Invalid $project :: caused by :: Cannot use expression other than
> $meta in exclusion projection

So, how can I get the desired output?

Thanks

Edit:

I removed `order_items: 0` from the project, and now I got this error message:

> PlanExecutor error during aggregation :: caused by :: $divide only
> supports numeric types, not array and int

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v5.0/reference/operator/aggregation/project/),

> If you specify the exclusion of a field other than _id, you cannot
> employ any other $project specification forms.

You should remove `order_items: 0`, because it is anyway not included in the output.

Comment: Thanks for your insight.. but I got this error now:
PlanExecutor error during aggregation :: caused by :: $divide only supports numeric types, not array and int